# CurrentTime script not working in Google Doc

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Google Doc is supposed to update with the current time when edits are made in 2 columns in front of it.

So if column B or C are edited, then column D updates with the current time.

```
function updateDate() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Daily");
  var active_sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getName();

  var active_col = s.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var active_row = s.getActiveCell().getRow();

  var target_rows = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20];
  var target_cols = [2, 3]
  var row_in_range = target_rows.indexOf(active_row) == -1 ? false : 
true; Logger.log(row_in_range);
  var col_in_range = target_cols.indexOf(active_col) == -1 ? false : 
true; Logger.log(col_in_range);

  if (row_in_range && col_in_range) {
    s.getRange(active_row, 4).setValue(new Date);
    s.getRange(active_row, 5).setValue(new Date);
  }
}
```

Not getting an error from Stackdriver logs but it is not working.

Comment: Just a hunch, but since you're aren't using `active_sheet` after setting it, maybe you need `var active_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();` and `var active_col = active_sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();` etc? Also, when is that function called? Did you set it as event handler? (also JavaScript and Java are two very different languages)

Comment: Why is this tagged with Java? Don't you know the name of the language that you're programming in?

Answer (score 1):

#### Goal:

A function that writes a timestamp in the respective row when either columns B or C are edited.

---

#### Solution:

This is all you really need. It's a small script that'll run **automatically** using a simple `onEdit` trigger whenever the sheet is edited. All it does is check the column that is edited using event objects then writes a timestamp in column D.

**Note: you won't be able to run this code manually, it runs automatically when the sheet is edited.**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if ((col === 2 || col === 3) === true) {
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    sh.getRange(row, 4).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

---

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [`setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))

Comment: The function onEdit script worked!  Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @JoleneSlama, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.